# Date format in RecordSet

Tags: delphi

I need to store a date in a Recordset. I am doing it as follows:

```
rs: _Recordset;
dt: TDatetime;

Rs := CoRecordset.Create;
Rs.Fields.Append('Date', adDate, 4, adfldupdatable, Unassigned);    
Rs.Fields.Item['Date'].Value := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy', TDatetime)
```

But, in the Recordset the date appears in format d/m/yyyy

How can I store dd/mm/yyyy in the recordset?

Comment: Do you mean "RecordSet"?  In any case, how exactly are you finding out that the field is stored in d/m/yyyy format?

Comment: Because I visualize it by saving a file as follows `Rs.Save ('D: \ Result.rs', 0);`

Comment: You haven't answered why you think the date is being stored in d/m/yyyy format.  Recordset date fields are not stored in string format at all, they are stored in binary format.  It is the s/ware you are using to display the RecordSet which determines the string format used to display dates.  Most likely the s/ware is displaying date fiekds using the date format set in your system's Date settings - try looking there.

Comment: In any case, why are you attempting to use RecordSets and ignoring the TAdoxxxx components (TAdoQuery, TAdoTable, etc) which are supplied with Delphi to make working with databases simple?

Answer (score 0):

The adDate is not a string format, it is a date format.  When you set value, it is performing a conversion from the string you entered into its internal format (which renders as d/m/yyyy when saved to a file).

If you want a specific string format for your date, use a string field to store the date. The disadvantage is that you are going to then need to make sure that you process the string field properly if you change your region settings to one where the date format is in M/D/Y order instead of what you stored as D/M/Y order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I cannot get your code to function as you claim.  In any case, it is clearly in error
because the line

```
Rs.Fields.Item['Date'].Value := FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy', TDatetime)
```

is wrong, because you are passing `TDateTime` as the second argument, not your
`dt` variable you apparently intend.

So, instead, using Delphi 10.4.2. I have compiled and run this program on Win10

```
program RecordSetTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Win.ComObj, WinAPI.ActiveX, WinAPI.AdoInt;

var
  RS: _Recordset;
  DT: TDatetime;
begin
  CoInitialize(Nil);
  DT := Now;
  RS:= CoRecordset.Create;
  RS.Fields.Append('Date', adDate, 4, adfldupdatable, Unassigned);
  RS.Open('c:\temp\rsdata.xml', EmptyParam, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, 0);

  RS.AddNew('Date', FormatDateTime('dd/MM/yyyy', DT));

  RS.Save('c:\temp\rsdata.xml', adPersistXML);

  RS := Nil;

  writeln('saved');
  readln;
end.
```

Note the call to AddNew, which is necessary to add a data record to the RecordSet file.

On my system, which has short and long date formats of dd/MM/yyyy and dd MMMM yyyy, the file
written is as follows:

```
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
  xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
  xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
  xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
<s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'>
  <s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly' rs:updatable='true'>
    <s:AttributeType name='Date' rs:number='1' rs:write='true'>
      <s:datatype dt:type='dateTime' rs:dbtype='variantdate' dt:maxLength='16' rs:precision='0' rs:fixedlength='true'
       rs:maybenull='false'/>
    </s:AttributeType>
    <s:extends type='rs:rowbase'/>
  </s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
  <z:row Date='2021-10-20T12:32:59'/>
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

Note the format of the date value

```
2021-10-20T12:32:59
```

despite the formatting of the date value in

```
      RS.AddNew('Date', FormatDateTime('dd/MM/yyyy', DT));
```